# How to override admin-bar style

Tags: functions, wp-admin, templates

How can I override the admin-bar so that it matched the style of the backend admin area of Wordpress? Should that disable the default and clone the admin-bar.css and modify that file is good idea?

Answer (score 10):

You can override admin-bar with this function, don't need to mess with `admin-bar.css`.

**Steps:**

1. Write your css
2. Put inside the function (given below)
3. Add this inside `functions.php`

   ```
   // customize admin bar css
   function override_admin_bar_css() { 

      if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) { ?>


         <style type="text/css">
            /* add your style here */
         </style>

      <?php }

   }

   // on backend area
   add_action( 'admin_head', 'override_admin_bar_css' );

   // on frontend area
   add_action( 'wp_head', 'override_admin_bar_css' );
   ```

Comment: +1 but on `wp_head` you should probably check first if the admin bar is displayed at all, to prevent the CSS being added for not logged in users

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun, added the condition to check if admin bar is displaying.

Comment: Could you actually explain what the different parts of your solution do? What is "backend area" and what is "frontend area"?

Comment: @posfan12 the backend area is the dashboard and the frontend is referring to the web page previews portion. Everything is self-explanatory, not sure what exactly is unclear for you.